# How to create alphabetical section headers with NSFetchedResultsController - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate a tableView. The tableView can get quite long because it shows a list of people, and I want to sort it alphabetically. I know I need to use `titleForHeaderInSection`, but I am stuck on how to get the first letter of each object in my `fetchedObjectsController.fetchedObjects` and display that as the section header as well as sort it, just how the Contacts app works.

This is what my View Controller looks like.

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Client> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Client> = Client.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    return NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "name", cacheName: nil)
}()

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else { return 0 }
    return sections.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else { return 0 }
    return sections[section].numberOfObjects
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientCell", for: indexPath)
    let client = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = client.name

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let client = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        ClientController.sharedController.delete(client)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very small example of how you can get your headers texts, I use a class only for test that have only name, then applying `map` using `characters.prefix` we get the first characters of the names and after casting to `String` and sorting we have what you need

```
var arrayOfUsers : [User] = [User(name:"test"),User(name:"pest"),User(name:"aest"),User(name:"nest"),User(name:"best")]
let finalArray = arrayOfUsers.map({String.init($0.name.characters.prefix(1)) }).sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
debugPrint(finalArray)
```

Console log result

> ["a", "b", "n", "p", "t"]

Hope this helps you